# Pyspark - Fill.na position changes .when condition outcome

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Apologies for the very general question:

I have a pyspark dataframe, and I apply a `fill.na` and a `when` condition to it, in the following manner:

```
df2 = df.withColumn('A', F.when( (F.col('B') != 'qqq') & (F.col('C) != 'vvv') ,1).otherwise(0)).na.fill('').groupby('X').sum("A").toPandas()
```

If I run a count for a specific value of X, I get a count like this:

```
df2.loc[df2['X'] == '2018-12-10'] 
# count value is 5000
```

If however, I place the `fill.na` part of the code, at the beginning, I get a different result:

```
df2 = df.na.fill('').withColumn('A', F.when( (F.col('B') != 'qqq') & (F.col('C) != 'vvv') ,1).otherwise(0)).groupby('X').sum("A").toPandas()

df2.loc[df2['X'] == '2018-12-10'] 
# count value is 170000
```

By digging a bit more, I found that in this second case, the when conditions are being ignored, therefore I get a much larger number of records.

Can anyone tell me what might be a reason for this? Does it have to do with how spark builds its  lazy evaluation of the dataset?

Thank you.

Comment: look into data of both of the dataframes before grouping..

Answer (score 1):

In the first approach when your columns `B` and `C` are `null`, column `A` will become 0 and therefore your sum will be low. On the other hand in the second approach when you first replace `null` values by empty string, column `A` will become 1 and so your final sum will be larger.